# What does it mean that I have a green "LV" cicular logo/symbol on my mounted drive

Tags: 12.04, unity

I have a local mounted disk which bears my Ubuntu 12.04 OS. The disk icon on the Unity dock has a green "LV" circular label on it.

Any ideas what this label means ..I cannot find any documentation on this

I am pasting a snapshot if it

[image: Green LV icon on mounted disk]

Answer (score 2):

It means it is a logical volume
see : http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/36568/what-is-logical-volume-management-and-how-do-you-enable-it-in-ubuntu/ for more info